# DateTime.Date conversion in EF Core Generated Query

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

We have a project we are working on and we need to query the database for some data for a particular date.

We configured our DB to read and write date as UTC.

When writing the query to get the data, I noticed that the data for a date was not being pulled from the database.

Here is the code:

```
transactionDate = Convert.ToDateTime("2021-11-10:T10:00:00").ToLocalTime();

var transactions2 = _transactionsRepo.Query()
  .Where(transaction => transaction.AccountId == pharmacy.AccountId.Value)
  .Where(transaction => transaction.TransactionDate.Date == transactionDate.Date)
  .OrderByDescending(transaction => transaction.TransactionDate)
  .Skip(numToSkip)
  .Take(pageSize);
```

On investigation, I noticed that when pulling the data, the DB returns the date as UTC as it should and the date is compared to the input date. But no data is returned. I checked the query generated and noticed this:

```
DECLARE @__transactionDate_1 datetime = '2021-11-10T10:00:00.000';
DECLARE @__p_2 int = 0;
DECLARE @__p_3 int = 10;

SELECT *
FROM [WalletTransactions] AS [w]
WHERE ([w].[AccountId] = @__AccountId_Value_0) AND (CONVERT(date, [w].[TransactionDate]) = @__transactionDate_1)
ORDER BY [w].[TransactionDate] DESC
OFFSET @__p_2 ROWS FETCH NEXT @__p_3 ROWS ONLY
```

From the above, the query generated shows that the `TransactionDate` is converted to just `Date` and compared to the input date `@__transactionDate_1` which is in `DateTime` form.

Any help on how to solve this will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Why not use `transactionDate = Convert.ToDateTime("2021-11-10:T10:00:00").ToLocalTime().Date` and then `.Where(transaction => transaction.TransactionDate.Date == transactionDate)`?

Comment: Also it's probably going to be more efficient to use `>` and `<` for example `.Where(t => t.TransactionDate >= transactionDateStart && t.TransactionDate < nextTransactionDateStart)`

Comment: We store them as `DateTimeOffset` for some reason. Then you only have to convert them to local time in your application. I think it’s because you'd want to store time independent of where you are (like when next year, we'll be living on Mars...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone facing the same issue, here is a link to the resolution on EF core repo on github:

https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/28380

The issue was caused by a custom value converter that saves and reads all date as UTC.

This means a double conversion was happening and skewing the date time.

Solution is to specify that the input date is in UTC and hence should not be converted.